# Flutter model not defined

Tags: flutter

I am receiving a errors in the data.dart for the category.categoryName and the category.imageUrl items.

I will get the following message
*The setter 'categoryName' isn't defined for the type 'List'.
Try importing the library that defines 'categoryName', correcting the name to the name of an existing setter, or defining a setter or field named 'categoryName'.*

They are defined in category_model.dart. What exactly am I doing wrong?

**data.dart**

```
import 'package:rss_tutorial/models/category_model.dart';

List<CategoryModel> getCategories() {
  List<CategoryModel> category = List<CategoryModel>();
  CategoryModel categoryModel = CategoryModel();

  category.categoryName = 'Recent';
  category.imageUrl =
      '';

  category.add(categoryModel);
}
```

**category_model.dart**

```
    class CategoryModel {
    String categoryName;
    String imageUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to wrong variable name usage.
Fixed below

```dart
categoryModel.categoryName = 'Recent';
categoryModel.imageUrl = //url here
```